# geth will not recognizw --mintme flag

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have been trying to run
`geth --mintme`  however only get `flag provided but not defined: -mintme`
I have searched the documentation, here https://github.com/etclabscore/core-geth/blob/master/cmd/utils/flags.go that shows mintme flags, but the documentation here doesn't https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options
This is the full command I am trying to run `geth --mintme --nousb --nodiscover --maxpeers 0` ,

Comment: can you provide the geth version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Geth fork that you linked to? The official Ethereum Geth repo [doesn't](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/flags.go) have this flag, so if you're trying to use that version, your outcome is as expected. If you are using the linked version of Geth from etclabscore, I don't see a reason this wouldn't work, and you should file an issue on that repository

Comment: I am not sure if I am so I probably not. Did not realize there was a fork.